# How play video from /data/data/package_name/files

Tags: android

I want to play video file from  /data/data/package_name/files in Android. I used Eclipse IDE to develop the android application.

How i can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code lines,

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.mypackage/myfile");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
```

OR:

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(path); // Here path is your video file path place in internal storage
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

But make sure your video file in internal storage has `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` permission..
Bco'z **MediaPlayer requires that the file being played has world-readable permissions**.